# excluding author and institute from title in llncs class

Tags: titles, lncs

I am using llncs class, and I would like to separately manipulate title and the names of the authors. That is, title would be where it already is by default, and text about authors and email/institution information would be placed somewhere left on the page. It is not a CV, just a specific article formatting.

For instance, I would like to have something like this:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

 \title{Title}
 \author{Author One{1} \and Author Two\inst{2}}
 \institute{Institution One \email{email at something}
           \and 
            Institution Two \email{another @ something}}

\begin{document}

% just title here? outside of the table
\maketitle

\begin{tabular}{l | r}    
% here I would like to have details about authors and institutions
\author{...} 
& 
%this is the abstract and keywords part
\begin{abstract}
%abstract content
\keywords{keyword1, keyword2}
\end{abstract}

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I was thinking of maybe redefining `\maketitle`, that was already redefined in llncs. Yet, I am not that good at low-level LaTeX and I have difficulties with this approach. Every attempt results in a document that is not compiling.

This is output for `\makeatletter\meaning\@maketitle\makeatother`:

```
macro:->\newpage \markboth {}{}\def \lastand {\ifnum \value {@inst}=2\relax
\unskip {} \andname \Ӏ\else \unskip \lastandname \Ӏ\fi }\def \and {\stepco-
unter {@auth}\relax \ifnum \value {@auth}=\value {@inst}\lastand \else \un-
skip , \fi }\begin {center}\let \newline \\ {\Large \bfseries \boldmath \preto-
lerance =10000 \@title \par }\vskip .8cm \if !\@subtitle !\else {\large \bfseries
\boldmath \vskip -.65cm \pretolerance =10000 \@subtitle \par }\vskip .8cm\fi
\setbox 0=\vbox {\setcounter {@auth}{1}\def \and {\stepcounter {@auth}}\def
\thanks ##1{}\@author }\global \value {@inst}=\value {@auth}\global \va-
lue {auco}=\value {@auth}\setcounter {@auth}{1}{\lineskip .5em \noindent
\ignorespaces \@author \vskip .35cm} {\small \institutename } \end {center}
```

For example, I have tried:

```
\def\@maketitle{\newpage
 \markboth{}{}%
 \begin{center}%
 \let\newline\\
 {\Large \bfseries\boldmath
  \pretolerance=10000
  \@title \par}\vskip .8cm
\if!\@subtitle!\else {\large \bfseries\boldmath
  \vskip -.65cm
  \pretolerance=10000
  \@subtitle \par}\vskip .8cm\fi
 \end{center}%
 }
```

This is compiling, though, but not working. Authors and institutes are again displayed together with title.

Is there maybe some other approach to separately manipulate title and authors&email&institutions?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) of a document that includes the basic document 'metadata' (title, authors, etc.) Redefining `\maketitle` may well be the way to go....

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: You don't have to use `\maketitle`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Comment: @Johannes_B but this again does not allow me to separately manipulate title from another details. And there is `\maketitle` command. Or maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not using `\maketitle` and setting the components of the title separately:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\title{A title}
%\author{An author}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

% Title
\begin{center}
  \Large\bfseries\boldmath
  A title
\end{center}

% Author and institution detail
\noindent\begin{tabular}{l @{~} | @{~} l}
  First Author  & First author institution details \\
                & Some more relevant institution detail \\
  Second Author & Second author institution details \\
                & Perhaps more content
\end{tabular}

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
  \keywords{keyword1, keyword2}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @concrete_rose See, no `\maketitle` ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B but there was `\maketitle` in the example :) :)
@Werner is it possible to put `\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}` in place of, e.g. First Author? I would like it to be also a member of the table

Comment: This is not a good solution since it reduces the number of used pages.